# Looping through array inside script block in Pug/Jade

Tags: node.js, express, pug

How do I loop through an array inside a script block in Pug/Jade?

Pug Code:

```
script.
  var arr = {for each val in ['a', 'b'] + ","};
```

Desired output

```
var arr = {'a','b',};
```

The code here outputs the line verbatim.

Comment: Why do you need to loop through the array using Pug/Jade? Can you rewrite the verbatim js to do the looping for you in js?

Comment: You are asking for invalid JavaScript to be output - `{'a','b',}` (and `{'a','b'}` will both cause errors in any JavaScript engine (`Error: Parse error on line 1:
{ 'a', 'b'}
--^
Expecting 'STRING', '}', got 'undefined'`)

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to read between the lines here and assume that you don't really want to output an invalid JavaScript object:

```
var arr = {'a','b',};
```

In an object you must follow the `{key:value, key:value}` pattern and this is just `{key,key}`.  The trailing comma won't be fatal, but it's probably not wanted either.

Instead, let's assume that you want an array output in a valid format like this:

```
var arr = ['a','b'];
```

In this case you need to use [unescaped interpolation](https://pugjs.org/language/interpolation.html) as you're inside a [plain text](https://pugjs.org/language/plain-text.html) block (caused by the period at the end of the script tag).

```
var arr = !{arrayVariable};
```

To be a little more safe in case your route doesn't pass that variable to the template you can do this:

```
var arr = !{arrayVariable || []};
```

To be specific and go back to exactly what you asked for, this code will work for the use case above:

```
var arr = !{["a", "b"]};
```

Comment: This did not answer my problem. I need to iterate over the arrayVariable inside the block and do different things with each item. Need to loop using jade inside the script block.